# syntax error: unexpected $end at token "<EOF>" GLSL with any shader

Tags: c++, opengl

I've seen other similar questions, and I now that it's usually due to wrong shader loading code, but I've tried with lots of different ways to load them, and I always get this error. Here is the loading code I'm currently using (for the Vertex shader, i do the same for the fragment shader):

```
GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
std::string VertexShaderCode;
std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
        VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    VertexShaderStream.close();
}
GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
int InfoLogLength;


// Compile Vertex Shader
printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

// Check Vertex Shader
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
```

I've also tried this:

```
    GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    std::ifstream shaderFile(vertex_file_path);
    //Error out here.
    stringstream shaderData;
    shaderData << shaderFile.rdbuf();  //Loads the entire string into a string stream.
    shaderFile.close();
    const std::string &VertexShaderCode = shaderData.str(); //Get the string stream as a std::string.
    GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
    int InfoLogLength;
    printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
    char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
    glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
    glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

    // Check Vertex Shader
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
    glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
```

And this is the linking code:

```
// Link the program
fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

// Check the program
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage( max(InfoLogLength, int(1)) );
glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
```

I have also tried passing `(GLint *)VertexShaderCode.size()` instead of NULL to the length parameter of glShaderSource(), but I get the same errors. I get those errors both when compiling and when linking

In case it helps, I'm using Opengl 3.3, GLEW, GLFW, Visual c++ 2010, and windows 7 64 bits

Comment: This happens if you don't specify the close bracket `}` at the end of the program :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you pass the length parameter to glShaderSource. The typecast you performed should trigger you a thick fat warning. The proper way would have been to put the result of `size()` into a variable. And then you give the pointer to that variable to glShaderSource.

Comment: Thanks! I was doing it the wrong way. But I've corrected it now saving it to a size_t variable and then typecasting that variable to (GLint *), and I still get the same errors

Comment: @XaitormanX: Why do you typecast at all. You should take a pointer from it: `size_t sourcelength = ...size(); glShaderSource(..., 1, &sourcestring, &sourcelength);`

Comment: because i get this error: `cannot convert parameter 4 from 'size_t *' to 'const GLint *'`

Comment: Fixed! It was a really stupid error, after all. I tried hard coding the vertex shader to a string instead of loading it from a file and it worked, so I supposed the part of loading the string from the file was failing. I checked the project's directory and realized that I only had added the file references to the project, and not the actual shader files. After adding those file to the project it works fine, sorry for making such a stupid question!
But as your corrections to my code were correct and necessary (If i decided to pass the length instead of null), I'll accept your answer anyways