# "syntax error, unexpected $end" when compiling GLSL programs?

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I'm having trouble compiling shaders. I'm pretty sure the issue is with my file loading code.

These are the relevant functions:

```c
char* loadShader(char* filename){
    char* buffer = 0;
    long length;
    FILE* f = fopen (filename, "rb");
    if(!f){
        // error reading file
        printf("failed to open file\n");
    }

    if (f){
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = malloc (length+1);
        if (buffer){
            fread (buffer, 1, length, f);
        }
        fclose (f);
    }
    return buffer;
}

Renderer* initRenderer(){
    Renderer* renderer = malloc(sizeof(Renderer));
    //renderer->vertices[0] = -0.5f; 
    float verts[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
    };
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        renderer->vertices[i] = verts[i];
    }
    glGenBuffers(1, &renderer->VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, renderer->VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(renderer->vertices), renderer->vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GLchar* vst = (GLchar*)loadShader("game_data/assets/shaders/simple_vert.glsl");
    GLchar* fst = (GLchar*)loadShader("game_data/assets/shaders/simple_frag.glsl");
    const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = vst;
    const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = fst;
    if(vst){free(vst);}
    if(fst){free(fst);}
    int  success;
    char infoLog[512];
    unsigned int vertexShader;
    vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n");
        printf("%s\n", infoLog);
        //std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    unsigned int fragmentShader;
    fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success)
    {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        printf("ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n");
        printf("%s\n", infoLog);
        //std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    return renderer;
}
```

The vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

And finally the error message:

```
ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED
0:1(1): error: syntax error, unexpected $end

ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED
0:1(1): error: syntax error, unexpected $end
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple with the strings. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227847/syntax-error-unexpected-end-at-token-eof-glsl-with-any-shader) answer with a similar problem but I wasn't able to glean anything from it.

Comment: You're `free`ing `vst` and `fst` before they are actually used.

Comment: ... additionally the shader source code is not 0-terminated. Do `buffer[length] = 0;`